# Show that $L$ is formally self-adjoint.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Consider the differential operator $$L=e^xD^2+e^xD,\;\;D=\frac{d}{dx},\;0\leq x\leq1,$$ $$u^\prime(0)=0,\;\;\; u(1)=0.$$ Show that $L$ is formally self-adjoint.

I just don't really know how to start this. I'm not quite sure how "formally self-adjoint" is different from just "self-adjoint". Any help/hints would be welcome.

Comment: probably you should use integration by parts formula.

Comment: See these references:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74579/definition-of-formally-self-adjoint

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#Formal_adjoint_in_one_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f,g\in dom(D^2)$, recall that $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$ and $f(1)=g(1)=0$.

$$\begin{align*}
\langle Lf,g \rangle &= \int\limits_0^1(e^xf_{xx}+e^xf_x)gdx \\
&=\int\limits_0^1gd(e^xf_x) \\
&=\overbrace{ge^xf_x\Big|_0^1}^{=0} - \int\limits_0^1e^xf_xg_xdx\\
&=- \int\limits_0^1e^xf_xg_xdx\\
&=- \int\limits_0^1e^xg_xdf\\
&=\overbrace{g_xe^xf\Big|_0^1}^{=0} + \int\limits_0^1f(g_xe^x)'dx\\
&=\int\limits_0^1f(e^xg_x+e^xg_{xx})dx = \langle f, Lg \rangle,
\end{align*}$$

conclude.

Comment: So "formally adjoint" is the same as "adjoint"?  Also, is $dom(D^2)$ the domain of $D^2$?

Comment: Yes it is. Basically, we always need it to write $Lf$.